# tapply with an ordered factor

Tags: r, r-factor, tapply

When a factor level is missing you can use table in the following way:

```
marks <- c(1,5,3,4,5,6)
table(ordered(marks,levels=1:6))
```

which will return a table with level "2" listed with zero frequency.

If there were a set of "scores" associated with the "marks" and there were no missing levels (here 2), `tapply` could be used to generate the sum of scores for each level.

```
tapply(scores,marks,sum)
```

Can tapply be adapted to the 'missing' factor levels case? Or is there a better way?

Comment: by the way, this will work just as well with `factor` as with `ordered`.  Specifying the levels explicitly is the key.

Answer (score 1):

The idea here is to emulate  **table** function behavior.

First , I generate a score vector ,
    scores <- sample(1:6)

then in 2 steps:

1. tapply to get scores with NA on missng values. Here I use sum function like table function but we can use any custom function ( max, min,..)

   ```
    res <- tapply( scores , ordered(marks,levels=1:6),function(x) {sum(x)} )
   ```
2. Then just replace missing values

   ```
    res[is.na(res)] <- 0
   ```